# Recuperar cookie com TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, script

olá, estou passando um código jQuery que eu estava desenvolvendo, para TypeScript... Eu havia feito em Jquery uma recupração de cookies que estava funcionando perfeitamente.

O que eu preciso é passar para a avriável, o valor de um cookie específico, da mesma forma que é mostrado no código que está em jQuery.

Enfim, vou deixar o código para vocês conseguirem me ajudar.

jQuery:

```
var numeroSerie = $.cookie('ns');
var user = $.cookie('user');

$('#numeroSerie').val(numeroSerie);
$('#user').val(user);
```

TypeScript:

```
var numeroSerie = document.cookie;
var user = document.cookie;

(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('numeroSerie')).value = numeroSerie;
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('user')).value = user;
```

Quando eu recupero oque está em `document.cookie`, obtenho a seguinte resposta:

> undefined=true; remember=true; rempass=true; rem_pass=true;
>   pass=asdexpires=7; check_rem_pass=trueexpires=7;
>   remember_pass=trueexpires=7; ns=asd; user=asd; check_rem_login=null;
>   remember_login=null; remember_pass

Comment: Cookies são armazenados como uma única string, o que o jQuery faz é um parse dessa string para recuperar o valor de cada chave. Como JS, e por extensão TS, não possuem um parse de cookies nativo, você terá que criar o seu, ou usar algum já pronto, mas a sua pergunta não deixa clara seu objetivo. Você quer transformar esse código em TS porque você não pode usar jQuery, ou apenas porque porque você quer o código TS? Porque se esse for o caso, você pode baixar `@types/jquery` para ter o jQuery com suporte a TS.

Comment: estou transformando todo o meu código jQuery para TS, pois foi um pedido da empresa. Então irei deixar de usar o jQuery e passar tudo para TS. @user140828

Comment: jQuery e TS não são mutualmente exclusivos. TS é um superconjunto de JS, você ainda usará bibliotecas e frameworks com TS. Você pode usar TS com jQuery, Lodash, Moment, React, Vue, nada disso torna seu código menos TS. A pergunta é, você precisa desse parse sem jQuery? Porque você pode ter esse código em jQuery e em TS ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @user140828, então cara, graças a sua primeira resposta, eu conversei aqui, e me disseram que poderia sim usar o jQuery com o TS, mas não é o ideal sabe? se tivesse uma maneira de eu não usar, seria melhor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o que você precisa é de um parse de cookies sem `jQuery`, você pode utilizar a função sugerida pela [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
function getCookie(cname: string): string {
    const name = cname + '=';
    const decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    const ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Basta invoca-la passando o nome do cookie

```
const ns = getCookie('ns');
const user = getCookie('user');
```

Comment: Obrigado, realmente funcionou para esses dois, porém eu deixei apenas esses dois só como forma de exemplo. Se eu quiser pegar mais dados desses cookies, usando esta função é só eu fazer da mesma forma que vc fez com o ns e o user? Ou é necessário mudar alguma coisa na função?

Comment: Pode deixar, consegui fazer tudo funcionar aqui, obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente e de forma bem simples.